# Python, Tkinter: How to redirect the output of a function to a notebook tab?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am wondering if it is possible to redirect the output of a function to a tab in the ttk notebook widget.

I assumed it would be similar to the listbox widget where you just used `listbox.insert` but I can not get this to work.

I apologize if this is a simple question but its really stumped me and I am unable to find any helpful material online to help me.

thanks in advance

Im using python 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Insert function works almost the same, the only difference is instead of taking a string it takes a frame. Add is a lot simpler though, you don't need to specify an index it just adds it to the end. All you need to do is create a frame, pack a Text element into it, and then pack the whole thing into the notebook. It would look something like this

```
noteb = ttk.Notebook( root, width=500, height=300 )
frame1 = tkinter.Frame( noteb )
textbox = tkinter.Text( frame1, put whatever you want to put here )
frame1.pack( expand=1, fill='both' )
noteb.add( frame1, whatever parameters you want )
noteb.pack( expand=1, fill='both' )
```

You should then be able to change the text in textbox directly.

Comment: thanks very much works perfectly, easy to understand example.

Answer (score 1):

Depends somewhat on what type of widgets you use as tabs, but basically it shouldn't be very different. Just keep track of your tab widgets and call the appropriate method.

Example with two Text tabs:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Notebook

def addText(tab):
    tab.insert(END, "foo! ")

root = Tk()

nb = Notebook(root, height=240, width=480)
tabs = {"foo": [], "bar": []}

for tabname in tabs:
    tab = Text(nb)
    tabs[tabname] = tab
    nb.add(tab, text= tabname)
nb.pack()

Button(root, text= "Add text!", command = lambda: addText(tabs["foo"])).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Clicking the "Add text!" button appends some text to the first tab.